# windows 2008 always keep local dns in first

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory

I have a windows 2008 system and it always keep ::1 in first of the dns setting.

I can see the following in "ipconfig /all":

```
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                      8.8.8.8
                                      8.8.4.4
```

and "Obtain dns server address automatically" option in network interface setting is disabled.

I installed active directory once and uninstalled now, I think it's the reason.

But I can't find any answer from google or bing how to fix.

Comment: Did you try removing it from the list of DNS servers?

Comment: I can't find any way to remove it, I can remove 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 but then DNS Servers only show ::1.

Comment: It's an IPv6 address, you have to remove it from the list of IPv6 DNS servers, not the IPv4 list.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I can removed it now, can you reply and let me mask your answer? It's a fool question but hard to find some information from google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::1` is an IPv6 address, so you have to remove it from the list of IPv6 DNS servers, not the IPv4 list. Windows unfortunately keeps two separate lists...